# How to Write Binary Data into Registry?

Tags: delphi, binary, registry

In Win7 RegEdit  edit or view a binary just like 1A 2B 3C 4D 
now I get a string

```
str := '1A,2B,3C,4D';
```

how to write str into  Registry , and in Win7 RegEdit it display  1A 2B 3C 4D

Comment: Your text says "binary" but your sample data shows `str`, which is obviously a string. Which is it you're asking about? Writing a string, or writing a binary value. They're not the same thing.

Comment: Your question is imprecise and vague. Be accurate and careful. Make sure we are clear what you are talking about. If English is not your strongpoint, use code to convey detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var
  Data: array of Byte; // or whatever binary container you want to use
  Reg: TRegistry;
begin
  ...
  SetLength(Data, 4);
  Data[0] := $1A;
  Data[1] := $2B;
  Data[2] := $3C;
  Data[3] := $4D; 

  Reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_SET_VALUE);
  try
    Reg.RootKey := ...;
    if Reg.OpenKey('...', True) then
    begin
      Reg.WriteBinaryData('Value', Data[0], 4);
      Reg.CloseKey;
    end;
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TRegistry.WriteBinaryData`. If you want to write binary `$1A,$2B,$3C,$4D` instead of string data `'1A,2B,3C,4D'` try to change it into `#$1A#$2B#$3C#$4D`.

```
str := #$1A#$2B#$3C#$4D;
```

and use `WriteBinaryData` to write the registry:

```
Reg.WriteBinaryData('KeyName', str, Length(str) * SizeOf(Byte));
```

Comment: That will not work in Delphi 2009+ unless `str` is an `AnsiString` or `RawByteString`.  Remember that `String` is now Unicode.